# Use "," in extended_valid_elements TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

I need to do the following whith TinyMCE:

```
extended_valid_elements: a[href|onclick=window.open(this.href,'_system','location=no');return false;]
```

When doing this the character "," causes me problems and does not appear the default "onclick".

Answer (score 0):

You can't put full code in `extended_valid_elements` - per the documentation (https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#extended_valid_elements) its expecting attributes and (optionally) their default text.  The JavaScript is not allowed and is messing up the parsing algorithm.

In `extended_valid_elements` you can reference `onclick` but you can't put the actual JavaScript in there.

If all you want is to allow JavaScript in your href values the `allow_script_urls` setting may do what you need without modifying `extended_valid_elements`:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/url-handling/#allow_script_urls